# struct initializer, typedef with visual studio

Tags: c, visual-studio

I wonder why the following does not work with Visual studio

```
typedef struct {
    float x, y;
} complexf;

typedef union {
    complexf f;
    long long d;
} rope;

int main(void)
{
    complexf a;
    rope z = {a};
}
```

The error is at line rope z = {a}, cannot convert from complexf to float. If the first member of the union is not a typedef, then it works. Is this a compiler bug, or a dark edge of C ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ANSI C standard (aka C89), 3.5.7:

> All the expressions in an initializer
>   for an object that has static storage
>   duration *or in an initializer list for
>   an object that has aggregate or union
>   type* shall be **constant expressions**.

The latter part of this restriction has been dropped in C99, which isn't properly supported by VS.

Comment: Thanks. I am a bit surprised that this is ok, though:

    rope z;
    z.f = a;

Comment: What exactly are you surprised about? That you can assign whole structeres? That's perfectly valid (for unions as well, but not for arrays).

Answer (score 1):

in VS 6.0 when I compile with /W4 I get

warning C4204: nonstandard extension used : non-constant aggregate initializer

so that makes me think it's not standard C and you are in compiler dependent land.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine on my `G++ 3.4.4` on `Cygwin`.

Except for the `':'` at the end needing a change to `';'`.
And, I changed `'__int64'` to `'long long'`.

---

With my stronger bias towards C for such code, I would have written,

```
 rope z = *(rope *)&a;
```

to force it on to the C++ compiler `:-)`.
But, don't do that...

The right way to go is of course, as David notes in his comment,

```
rope z; z.f = a;
```

Comment: the type punning through pointer is very ugly - I have never seen any case where it was useful. Union is much better for type punning.

Comment: Infact, it is likely to fool the compiler into overlooking your errors. Yet, I have seen it being used.

Comment: I've done type punning through pointer casts myself out of laziness, but using unions is preferable: GCC optimizes them better and they avoid possible alignment issues